# Retrieve first and last entry of hour with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have database to storing temperatures. There are three to five temperatures per hour and i want to get first and last temperature of an hour but i can't create suitable subquery.

Here is the main query to get temperatures by hour.

```
SELECT HOUR(time) AS h, max(temp_in) as max, min(temp_in) as min, count(temp_in) as count 
FROM tbl_temps 
GROUP BY h;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have many days' worth of measurements in this table? What do you want to do with the hours of different days?

Comment: I get once only one day resultset. That's not in this example and is not needed for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a union and subquery

```
select *  from 
my_table where (HOUR(time),MINUTE(time)) in (
        select HOUR(time), min(MINUTE(time))
        from my_table
        group by HOUR(time)
 )
union 
select *  from 
my_table where (HOUR(time),MINUTE(time)) in (
        select HOUR(time), max(MINUTE(time))
        from my_table
        group by HOUR(time)
)
order by HOUR(time), MINUTE(time)
```

Comment: Is there missing something, it said there is an error on row 4?

Comment: There missing two parentheses after each "min(MINUTE(time)" too but now it's working. Thank you.